# AWSIoTDataManager Not able to connect on iOS 17 devices. status is getting as unknown

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-sdk-ios

AWSIoTDataManager not getting connected on iOS 17 devices. I am calling `AWSIoTDataManager.connect(withClientId. statusCallback is not received even after waiting.

When manually check status of AWSIoTMQTTStatus it was unknown

SDK Version: 2.33.4
Dependency Manager: SPM
Swift Version : Swift 5
Xcode Version: Xcode 15.0 beta 7

Error received in logger:

Describe the bug
AWSIoTDataManager not getting connected on iOS 17 devices. I am calling `AWSIoTDataManager.connect(withClientId. statusCallback is not received even after waiting.

When manually check status of AWSIoTMQTTStatus it was unknown

Environment(please complete the following information):

SDK Version: 2.33.4
Dependency Manager: SPM
Swift Version : Swift 5
Xcode Version: Xcode 15.0 beta 7
Device Information (please complete the following information):

Device: iPhone XS, iPhone 14 Pro Max
iOS Version: iOS 17

**Logger output**

2023-08-30 12:34:23:974 XX_APP[1183:150181] getIdentityRef error: -25300
2023-08-30 12:34:23:974 XX_APP[1183:150181] Could not find SecIdentityRef

Comment: I am having the same issue